# Add JavaScript Reference in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

Below is my Problem :

[image]

GlobalJs.js is my custome JavaScript file and has only one line code alert(1).

[image]

But I am unable to add its reference in _Layout.cshtml.

[image]

src="../JavaScript/GlobalJs.js" or src="~/JavaScript/GlobalJs.js" none is working for me. What is the problem actually? Please anyone help me. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, static files such as javacript, css etc are serve to web browser from `wwwroot` folder.

Hence, you need to move these files into `wwwroot` folder and then reference files in `_Layout.cshtml` using `<script src="~/JavaScript/GlobalJs.js"></script>`

For more information, please refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)

Comment: Out of all the answers on SO explaining this, this answer is the easiest to understand :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core, Static files, such as HTML, CSS, image, and JavaScript, are assets that serve from wwwroot folder to web browser.

Hence, you need to move these files into wwwroot folder and then reference files in 
`_Layout.cshtml` using `<script src="~/JavaScript/GlobalJs.js"></script>`

**Note:** In order for static files to be served, you must configure the Middleware to add static files to the pipeline. The static file middleware can be configured by adding a dependency on the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` package to your project and then calling the UseStaticFiles extension method from `Startup.Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: this answer seems to duplicate the accepted one, or the other way around? :)

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem but my solution was to double check that the javascript file was copy to the solution. Easy to forget this configuration, right click on the file and select properties:

[image]